# How to reference friends in Open Graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am creating a Facebook-enabled game where the users will be able to publish 'friend passes'; where a player will be able to post (automatically) such as: 'I passed James Brown on MY_GAME'. I am using Open Graph for posting my actions. I've created an action named 'pass' and an object named 'friend'. Here is my properties (where 'friendpass' is a Friend reference):

[image: pass action]

I am trying to post actions such as 'Michael passed a friend on MY_GAME' and also tag my passed friend[s?]. How can I enable this functionality? Currently, I ve set up a page (actually just meta-tag) renderer and Here is an example rendered page:

```
 <html and other headers...>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="345390505541783">
    <meta property="og:type" content="smileys-game:friendpass">
    <meta id="ogurl" property="og:url" content="http://apps.canpoyrazoglu.com/smileys/pass/mehmet/sucuk">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Friend passed!">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png">
    <meta id="friendid" property="smileys-game:friend" content="735475141">
    <meta id="ogdesc" property="og:description" content="something comes here.">
    <rest of header and page...>
```

I use the debug tool to get what Facebook sees and there is a link to the action there as a Graph API call. When I click it it returns OAuth error, when I type that URL to the Graph API explorer, I get this:

[image: graph api call result]

Graph API sees my 'friend' object as a webpage, which is actually a reference to a Facebook ID (my own ID). How can I make use of that Friend ID useful and make a link to the friend in the post?

Thanks,
Can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create your action type, you need to use the `profile` object type (aka connected object type). Here I created my verb to "high five" a person:

[image: action type config]

The object type will be configured automatically because `profile` is a built-in, FB-provided object type. So you don't have to configure the object type, unless there's an advanced setting you need.

Then create an aggregation:

[image: aggregation config]

Your og meta tags for the object then need to use the type `profile` (filepath for this example is /og/profile2.html):

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# high_fiver: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/high_fiver#">
   <meta property="fb:app_id"      content="27877347222" />
   <meta property="og:url"         content="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/celebrity/tom_hanks/" />
   <meta property="og:type"        content="profile" />
   <meta property="og:title"       content="Tom Hanks" />
   <meta property="og:description" content="Tom Hanks profile on RT" />
   <meta property="og:image"       content="http://content6.flixster.com/rtactor/40/37/40376_pro.jpg" />
```

Notice that you can point to any `profile`, not just a FB profile. Above, I am using Tom Hanks' profile on Rotten Tomatoes, which uses Open Graph and has og:type `profile`.

And I publish actions like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function postAction() {
   FB.api(
     '/me/high_fiver:high_five' + '?profile=http://www.plooza.com/og/profile2.html',
     'post',
     function(response) {
       if (!response || response.error) {
         alert('Error occured');
         console.log(response.error);
       } else {
         alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
       }
     }
   );
 }
</script>
```

**Finally, a user of my app will publish the OG story on his/her timeline (in a "timeline unit"):**

[image: profile story unit]

When you click the link "Tom Hanks" in the story unit, it loads the Rotten Tomatoes profile.

You can try this demo app here:  http://plooza.com/og/profile2.html

Comment: this one really clarifies what I'm trying to achieve. thanks a lot. mine is quite similar (action-wise) but the object needs some changes, which I'll implement now.

Answer (score 1):

So “friend” is your own object type? How exactly is it defined?

I think for what you’re planning to do here, the built-in object type [Profile](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/#external_profile) might suit your needs better – because that already creates a tie to a Facebook profile that is recognizable as such by the Open Graph.

Comment: Friend is my own object type, and while designing the action, I saw 'Friend' there, and I didn't have any other object types and even though I typed 'friend' with lowercase, it was showing 'Friend' and I thought it was a built in type for referencing friends. I've just realized the object type I chose represents the one that I've created. so, I'll be removing that from my properties, but the question still applies.. is there any way to achieve what I was trying to achieve any way? How can I make use of the Profile type that you've linked. (of course besides creating OG tags)